# Using IIS, is it possible to use URL Rewrite to direct it to a specific HTML page?

Tags: html, url, iis

I am configuring a web map application using IIS and GeoServer (installed through OpenGeoSuite) on an AWS EC2 instance.

Using this tutorial (http://www.cartoninjas.net/post/Installing-GeoServer-on-Windows-7-(x32-or-x64)-and-IIS-75) I was successfully able to redirect my primary Web Server (IIS) to my secondary web server (GeoServer) using the URL Rewrite:

```
http://localhost:8080{R:0}
```

Now, I am having trouble editing the index.html page that is the default page. Notepad++ keeps denying any edits because it's being used in Java, but it allows me to edit with Notepad (?!). Instead of needing to edit in notepad and be tortured, I just want to use a different HTML page to represent that default page for my custom domain.

Is there a way in IIS to redirect to a specific HTML file through OpenGeoSuite's configuration of GeoServer?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a GIS topic, and a flag from one of our most experienced users has suggested that it may be more more suited to [sf].  I'm happy to try and migrate it there, if you (as its asker) want me to.  In any event you may want to be researching this more widely than here.

Comment: @PolyGeo oh I'm sorry, I'm still getting acclimated to this entire forum environment and the system side of things. Yes please, if you could migrate it there I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: These Q&A sites are not forums. The distinction is subtle to some but once you get it a lot becomes clearer.